# Поворот текстуры на плашке на 45 градусов

Tags: unity3d, геометрия, текстура

Есть плашка, на неё наложен материал с текстурой. Нужно несколько раз подряд повернуть текстуру на 45 градусов.
Как это сделать?

Тестовый проект, где я пытаюсь это делать через поворот UV: https://yadi.sk/d/T3KamjVKtQLqL
Исходный код из тестового проекта: http://pastebin.com/EKJ4Fg5L

В тестовом проекте ширина плашки идёт по её локальной оси Z -- это пришло из рабочего проекта, извиняюсь. Высота по Y как обычно.

Какие есть усложнения в реальной задаче по сравнению с тестовым проектом:

- Текстура может быть неквадратной
- Плашка может быть неквадратной (через localScale)
- У текстуры может быть задан физический размер (например, она должна занимать на плашке строго 0.5х0.2 "юнити-метров"), соотвественно, она будет тайлиться (через uv или через тайлинг материала -- мне оба способа подойдут), если её "физический размер" не совпадёт с таковым у плашки.

Сразу поясню, что не понимаю ни кватернионы, ни даже операции с векторами толком, поэтому очень прошу поподробнее объяснить.

Платформа: WebPlayer, WebGL.

Comment: что такое плашка ?? с unity не знаком, но если это поворот на плоскости то здесь естиь формулы и некоторые пояснения касательно поворотов https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82

Comment: Да, это поворот на плоскости. Спасибо за ссылку.